# I am trying a simple ng-repeat example and it is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is the code I am trying. How can I rectify the error?

```
<html ng-app="countryApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular.js Example</title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', []);
        countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function($scope, $http){
            $http.get('countriesgdp.json').success(function(data) {
                    $ scope.countries = data;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="CountryCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Population</th>
            <th>Flag</th>
            <th>Capital</th>
            <th><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_GDP_(PPP)">GDP (PPP)</a></th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="country in countries">
            <td>{{country.name}}</td>
            <td>{{country.population}}</td>
            <td><img src="{{ country.flagURL }}" width="100"></td>
            <td>{{country.capital}}</td>
            <td>{{country.gdp | currency}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you purposefully put space after $ sign  `$ scope.countries = data;` ? please console.log your `$scope.countries`. also check for errors in console. if any please post it.

Comment: Share what error are you getting and waht you want? The question doesn't tell anything .

Comment: check for the working example https://jsfiddle.net/ebinmanuval/wvuxoj03/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember doing Angular and having some trouble with scope not updating, you can try the following:

```
countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  $http.get('countriesgdp.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.countries = data;
  });
  $scope.$apply()
});
```

You can try adding a scope apply function after the get request.

Also it's possible that the structure of countriesgdp.json is incorrect, you might need to do something like this:

```
$scope.countries = data[0]
```

Please could you share the start of your JSON file so we can make sure the structure is correct, your code looks fine and should work.

Comment: JSON structure was missing due to which it was not able to print the output.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any error log on console? First, check it and then log data to console that returns server or try to display all the data on screen or put on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) demo.

```
<pre>{{ countries }}</pre>
```

Be sure to taking correct data from the server.

Answer (score 0):

> Actually if you found any error in console window . Then only we can provide exact answer. Any way please mind this following details.

- You should globally  initialize ng-repeat object as array in top of the controller.

```html
 <script>
                    var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', []);
                    countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function($scope, $http){
                        $scope.countries=[];// Should add this line
                        $http.get('countriesgdp.json').success(function(data) {
                                $scope.countries = data;
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

Because you will get module not defined error.

- And `$scope.countries` values are should be an array format. because `ng-repeate` only accept array of data. So you should check if the service is returning array of data or what.

rest of the code looks fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

yes change $ scope.countries to $scope.countries

also use console.log to verify that data is not empty.

Comment: Please don't post fixing typos as answers.

Comment: I have tried using $scope.countries and it is not working. Typos is not the issue here.